# Django many to many query with null form and model values

Tags: django, django-forms, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have the below model structure, where each Tradesman has a many-to-many relationship with two attributes; Language and Discipline. In the form, a user can select a subset of Tradesman by filtering on these attributes.

What I would like to happen, is that:

1. if the user filters only one attribute, the form selects all of the
   unfiltered attributes. Eg. if the select a select a language but
   leave the discipline blank, it does not filter on discipline.
2. if the user filters on a language where a tradesman does not have
   one set (i.e. it is null), it excludes that tradesman.

I think I can solve this by a baroque non-pythonesque, non-django method of extracting the primary keys from the query and using them, but would rather use a cleaner method.

What I think could solve it would be:

1. A dynamic django filter, that would drop or include conditions depending on if-else logic
2. A parameter that would match everything (including nulls) that I could store in a variable, eg.

   ```
    return_everything=**everything()!** 
    Q(discipline__id__in=return_everything)
   ```

I have been looking in the django docmentation and on stackoverflow and can't find a method to do either.
Thanks for any help.

models.py:

```
class Discipline(models.Model):  
    discipline=models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Language(models.Model):  
    language=models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Tradesman(models.Model):  
    discipline=models.ManyToManyField(Discipline, blank=True, null=True)
    language=models.ManyToManyField(Language, blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class TradesmanForm(forms.Form):
    #select all values to output in the form
    discipline_all=.Discipline.objects.all() 
    language_all=Language.objects.all() 

    #declare form variables
    discipline=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=discipline_all,required=False)  
    language=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=language_all,required=False) 

    #clean data
    def clean(self) 
        cleaned_data=super(TradesmanForm, self).clean()
        return cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
def TrademanLookup(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':      
        if form.is_valid()
            discipline=form.cleaned_data['discipline']
            language=form.cleaned_data['language']
            #################################################
            #  how can I make the below query dynamic,      # 
            #  or else pass a variable into it that selects # 
            #  everything, including nulls?                 #
            #################################################
            tradesman_return=Tradesman.objects.filter(
                Q(discipline__id__in=discipline),
                Q(language__id__in=language)
                )
            ...work with returned data...
        else:
            ...something else...
    else:
            ...something else...

    return render_to_response('some.html','somevar':somevar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def TrademanLookup(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':      
        if form.is_valid()
            discipline=form.cleaned_data['discipline']
            language=form.cleaned_data['language']
            query = []
            if disciplines:
                query.append(Q(discipline__in=discipline))
            if language:
                query.append(Q(language__in=language))

            if query:    
                tradesman_return=Tradesman.objects.filter(*query)
            else:
                tradesman_return=Tradesman.objects.all()

            #...work with returned data...
```

NB : it's considered GoodPractice(TM) to use plural forms for collections (should really be "disciplines" and "languages" in both the Trademan model and the form.

NB2 : the convention is to use all_lower_with_underscore names for functions, so your view should be named "trademan_lookup"

Comment: That works, thanks a million. As regards the NBs, the upper case view was a typo when simplifying the cod for stackoverflow, but doen't django pluralise models in the admin? I've been changing my code my model names from plural to singular for this reason; assuming that that meant it was best practice. Thanks again for your help.